# Possible to reflect changes to a plugin's composer.json without uninstall/reinstall?

Tags: plugin-development, composer

When working on a plugin recently, I decided to add a CP section:

**composer.json**

```
{
    ...
    "extra":
        ...
        "hasCpSection": true
    ...
}
```

The only way that I was able to have this change reflected in Craft was to uninstall/reinstall the plugin. Is there an alternate way (e.g. CLI) to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uninstall the plugin via CLI but I guess that's not really what you are after. The only other way is to change the auto generated config file in `vendor/craftcms/plugins.php` and change the parameter for your plugin there. But you can't ever change this attribute for others that downloaded your plugin remotely without doing things you should not do.